# Group Policy Preferences Filtering

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, group-policy, active-directory

I'm having issues getting a 2008 Policy to apply on my 2003 domain.
I attached Group Policy Management from a 2008 server to the domain and setup it's own policy. The policy is **User Configuration > Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Folder Options > Open With**.

I check gpresult on the computer and it shows that it is applied, but under Filter it says **Filtering:  Not Applied (Unknown Reason)**. I don't see anything in the event log. Under the group policy scope, I have security filtering set to apply this to all Authenticated Users.

How do I start to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method to check logs on Group Policy Preferences is to enable the **'Logging and tracing'** option for the type of preference you've configured.  You can find all the available items to optionally configure in

`Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > System > Group Policy > Logging and tracing`.  For folder options enable 'Configure Folder Options preference logging and tracing'.

As your question is a bit light on full details don't forget to verify the policy is linked to the OU where your user objects exist, you've configured a user setting so the policy should be linked in your domain where user objects exist.  If linked to computer objects you must enable loopback processing.

Comment: Yummy logs. Looks to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks